# How to deploy a Dialogflow bot on Google assistant that will call a number?

Tags: dialogflow-es, integration, google-assistant-sdk

I want to create a DialogFlow agent that will be Deployed on the Google Assistant that will get a Phone number from a backend service and will be able to call the number using the Google Assistant. Is it possible?

Comment: I'll describe a typical convo with Google Assistant that I require for my App.
User(U): "Ok Google, Show me the Tracker App"
Google Assistant(GA): "Sure, What is the user name you need?"(Invokes my DialogFlow Agent)
U:"The User Name is XXXX"
GA:"The details are as : 
Name: abcd
Phone Number: 11111"
U:"Please call the number"
GA:"Sure, calling User on number 1111"

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can only play sound files or play streams. The Google Assistant also doesn't provide you with the actual sound that was recorded as it always converts the detected sound to text. This text is then delivered to your Action.

You could however call someone from your back-end using Twilio by synthesizing the text that was detected. Responding to whatever the person you're calling says would be hard as well.

I usually opt for sending text messages instead of calling when using Actions.

Comment: I actually want to make a phone call using the Google Assistant, is that possible?

Comment: I'll describe a typical convo with Google Assistant that I require for my App. User(U): "Ok Google, Show me the Tracker App" Google Assistant(GA): "Sure, What is the user name you need?"(Invokes my DialogFlow Agent) U:"The User Name is XXXX" GA:"The details are as : Name: abcd Phone Number: 11111" U:"Please call the number" GA:"Sure, calling User on number 1111" Is something like this possible? –

Answer (score 0):

The platform does not support the ability to programmatically call telephone numbers through the user's phone.